# Python fifo opened from C blocks both processes; with nonblock it gives BlockingIOError

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pipe

I am using a pair of fifos for IPC between C and Python.  I create the fifos in C and open them in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os

pr = os.open('/tmp/Pipe_01', os.O_RDWR)
print("Read Opened")
pw = os.open('/tmp/Pipe_02', os.O_RDWR)
print("Write Opened")

while True:
    v = os.read(pr,3)
    print("Python read")
    print(v)
```

Python runs in a child process created by fork-execv by C.

My plan is that the C side writes to `/tmp/Pipe_01` and Python reads it, then Python writes to `/tmp/Pipe_02`.  The read side (`/tmp/Pipe_01`) should block in Python waiting for C, and the write side (`/tmp/Pipe_02`) should block while waiting for Python.

My problem is that the code shown above will block both processes as soon as the two fifos are opened, even when C has already written to `/tmp/Pipe_01` before the write.

If I make `/tmp/Pipe_01` nonblocking (`pr = os.open('/tmp/Pipe_01', os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK`) then I get:

```
v = os.read(pr,3)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I have researched this but no definitive answer because that message appears in many contexts other than pipes.  Many questions involve pipes created on the Python side with `os.mkfifo`, which is not the case here .

Ideally I want to make at least `/tmp/Pipe_01` blocking on the Python side, but when I do it blocks both processes and nothing proceeds.

On the C side I create both fifos this way:

```
int s = mkfifo(fifo_name, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
```

and open them this way:

```
c = open(fifo_name, O_RDWR);
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Pipes on Linux are unidirectional.  Whoever is writing should be using `O_WRITE`.  Whoever is reading should be using `O_READ`.  When a FIFO is opened for read, the process blocks until some process opens for write.

Comment: The problem is that when Python opens it (the first to open) both processes block.  So C is not able to open it after Python.  Also,  "module 'os' has no attribute 'O_READ'."

Comment: Probably because you have claimed both the "read" end and the "write" end.  There's nothing left for C to use.  Both ends are busy.  Fix the open statements.

Comment: Note that those are two separate FIFOs, /tmp/Pipe_01 and /tmp/Pipe_02.  How does that affect your comment?

Comment: It doesn't change a thing.  A pipe only has two ends.  If you claim both, then the pipe is busy.  In the C code, you'll open `Pipe_01` as O_WRITE and `Pipe_02` as O_READ.  In the Python code, you'll open `Pipe_01` as O_READ and `Pipe_02` as O_WRITE.

Comment: I'll change that and see if it still blocks on open.  It makes sense.  In fact, both C and Python are claiming both ends.  Which makes me wonder why there's a RDWR at all.

Comment: Well now the read side opens but the write side returns pw = os.open('/tmp/Pipe_02', os.O_WRONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK) -  No such device or address: '/tmp/Pipe_02'

Comment: You're sure you created both sides in the C code before opening either one?  If the C code opens the read side, it will block until Python opens the write side.  If you don't call `mkfifo` until afterward, then you have a race condition.

Comment: I don't use mkfifo in Python because I already created it in C.  Should I also use mkfifo in Python even though it's created in C?  I am now having some problems with blocking after making the changes you suggested, but I'm not yet clear on what the problem is.

Comment: No, no, no!  Whoever is FIRST needs to call `mkfifo`.  Here the scenario I was thinking.  If your C code does `mkfifo #1` / `open for read` / `mkfifo #2` / `open for write`, that's a problem because the first open will hang waiting for the other end, and FIFO #2 doesn't exist yet.  I'm just saying make the C code `mkfifo` / `mkfifo` / `open` / `open`.

Comment: Right now C is first, with c = open(fifo_name, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK); but it fails. I'm not showing perror correctly, so I'll get the error message.  Even without NONBLOCK it fails, whereas with RDWR it succeeds.  This pipe handoff could use some improvement; it confounds a lot of people apparently.

Comment: open: No such device or address - now I have a different problem to work on.  Your comments have been very helpful.  Thank you.